# What fields and syntax for constructor to create records to add to a list<object>

Tags: apex, list, master-detail, constructor

So I'm creating a list of child records for a parent using a loop.  Is there a way I can create the child record as I add it to the list instead of creating the object and setting the variables?

```
list<testObject> parentList = new List<testObject>();
parentList.add(new childObject(field1 = 'some value', field2 = 0.00);
```

If this is possible how do I reference the fields?

The long way to do this would be

```
list<testObject> parentList = new List<testObject>();
childObject tempChild = new childObject();
tempChild.field1 = 'some value';
tempChild.field2 = 0.00;
parentList.add(tempChild);
```

It seems less elegant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the first method does work; you just missed a `)`:

```
Account[] records = new Account[0];
records.add(new Account(Name='Test', Industry='Technology'));
```

Comment: hahaha!  The funny thing is I can't run this until my test classes are built so I doing this blind and free handed the example.  Glad I mostly got it!  Thanks for verifying!!!

Comment: @tjcinnamon by the way, using this method isn't just more elegant, it actually uses less CPU time, so you should always prefer this method.

Answer (score 3):

On the subject of clean initialization, if you have some fixed data that you want to include in a list you can use this initialization syntax:

```
list<testObject> parentList = new List<testObject>{
        new testObject(field1 = 'some value 1', field2 = 0.00),
        new testObject(field1 = 'some value 2', field2 = 0.00)
        };
```

[Similar mechanisms](https://force201.wordpress.com/2010/04/12/collection-initialization/) are available for sets and maps.